# Where to filter results based on authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

```
[Authorize]
public class ContactController{

    private readonly ContactService service;

    public ContactController(ContactService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Index() {
        var model = service.GetContacts();
        return View(model);
    }
} 

public class ContactService {

    private readonly ContactRepository repository;

    public ContactService(ContactRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> GetContacts() {
        var contacts = repository.GetAll();
        return contacts.Select(c=> new ContactViewModel(c));
    }
}

public class ContactRepository {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public ContactRepository(ApplicationDbContext context){
        db = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Contact> GetAll() {
        return db.Contacts;
    }
}
```

Now I want to only get contacts that are of the authenticated user. Let's say contact have a UserId property so,
I want to do .Where(c=> c.UserId == userId) 'somewhere';

Where is supposed that code to be ? On service? On repository? on Controller ?

An implementation on the service will be like this :

```
public class ContactService {

    private readonly ContactRepository repository;
    private readonly IIdentity identity;

    public ContactService(ContactRepository repository, HttpContext httpContext){
        if (context?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == false)
                throw new ArgumentException("Non authenticated request", nameof(httpContext));
            identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> GetContacts() {
        var contacts = repository.GetAll()
            .Where(c=> c.UserId == identity.GetUserId()); // <-- authorization logic.
        return contacts.Select(c=> new ContactViewModel(c));
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach? 
How are you doing it? Another layer?

Answer (score 0):

I would warn against publicly exposing IQueryable from your repository. Exposing the IQueryable means that the classes which leverage the repository determine when when the IQueryable actually gets resolved as a database round trip. This means your repository is hard to work with and fails to provide a clean separation of concerns.

For this reason, I use more specific interfaces on any database repository like

```
public Contact[] GetAllContacts() {}

public Contact GetContact(int userId) {}
```

Returning concretes like Lists and Arrays instead of IQueryable will force the  database round trip within the repository. The trade off is that it is more verbose, but worth it for the separation of concerns this provides.

[EDIT] For example - where does the database round trip actually occur in your code above? It actually doesn't happen until the view gets executed and actually reads the data from the model.

Comment: this means that my authorization logic goes in my repository.am I right?

Comment: nope. your service would just have public IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> GetContacts() {
        return repository.GetContrat(identity.GetUserId());
    } --- or better yet, private readonly Contract which is set in the constructor using the identity

Comment: in your example, you are using the authorization logic on repository.

Comment: in my example I'm not doing ToList() but that should be at least before mapping to the ViewModel. but that's offtopic :D The code I showed was to ask for where to put the : `Where(t=> t.UserId == userId)` code in a more general fashion not specific to this example.